# substitute space character in lua

Tags: lua, mediawiki-templates

I am creating a template in Wikipedia to link articles to an external website which is a book archive called fadedpage.com. I am generating a url to link to a specific author page. Part of the url is the author's name which contains one or more spaces. For example, the url for the author "Ian Fleming" is: http://fadedpage.com/csearch.php?author=Fleming, Ian. My template call structure is {{FadedPage|id=Fleming, Ian|name=Ian Fleming|author=yes}}.

For my template I am replicating an existing template which uses a script coded in lua to parse the template arguments. I have been able to generate all of the url except for the space character between the last and first name.

I could code the template call as: {{FadedPage|id=Fleming,%20Ian|name=Ian Fleming|author=yes}} which works OK but I would rather have the call format as it looks on the fadedpage website, ie. with the embedded space. So I need a way in lua to find the space character within the string and substitute it for the string "%20". So far I haven't figured out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about mediawiki templates, but if you have the string as, say, `str` then `str = str:gsub( " ", "%20" )` should do the trick. But I'm pretty sure that there should be a function for URL escaping somewhere (that's the "%xx" stuff), because that's a very common action when dealing with URLs. From some quick googling, it might be `str = mw.uri.encode( str, "PATH" )`.

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.

Comment: I think you need `"%%20"`.